# How to use keywords with `ps` (process status)?

Tags: bash, command-line, process, ps

I am trying to display memory usage of active processes using the command `ps`. I read in the manual that one can use the keyword `%mem` in association with `-O` or `-o` but I fail to understand how.

When I try that for example

```
ps -a -o=%mem
```

I get the list of keywords

```
%cpu %mem acflag acflg args blocked caught comm command cpu cputime etime f flags gid group ignored inblk inblock jobc ktrace
ktracep lim login logname lstart majflt minflt msgrcv msgsnd ni nice nivcsw nsignals nsigs nswap nvcsw nwchan oublk oublock p_ru
paddr pagein pcpu pending pgid pid pmem ppid pri pstime putime re rgid rgroup rss ruid ruser sess sig sigmask sl start stat state
stime svgid svuid tdev time tpgid tsess tsiz tt tty ucomm uid upr user usrpri utime vsize vsz wchan wq wqb wql wqr xstat
```

---

I know I can get this info with `top` as well but I would like to use `ps` as I don't think one can pipe output of `top` in a convenient fashion.

I use bash (Terminal version 3.6.1) on MAC OS X 10.11.3

Comment: Isn't this more appropriate for [Super User](https://superuser.com/)? I see nothing in your question relating to any of tags (`r`, `statistics`, `distribution`, and `probability-density`). Do you think R-using statisticians are more likely to know the inner-workings of the `ps` command-line utility? (You might be right ...)

Comment: @r2evans Sorry about the tags (now edited). I forgot to edit them after considering asking a question about R and stats.  The question might be equally on topic on Super User I would think (after all there a `ps` tag here on SO). I'm happy to migrate it or to close and reopen over there if other users think the question would be a better fit on SuperUser. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MacOS man page's syntax summary, emphasis added:

> ps [-AaCcEefhjlMmrSTvwXx] [-O fmt | **-o fmt**] [-G gid[,gid...]] [-g grp[,grp...]] [-u uid[,uid...]] [-p pid[,pid...]] [-t tty[,tty...]] [-U user[,user...]]

Notably, `-o fmt` is not `-o=fmt` -- and replacing `=` from your command with a space prevents the error in question.

Comment: Thank you! I was close :) My manual says `Keywords may be appended with an equals (=) sign and a string.`. I am not sure what it means if not that one can use `-o=%mem`

Comment: It means if you want a different header than `%MEM` in the output, you can do `-o %mem=foo` (to use the header `foo`). It's admittedly rather unclear grammar; if I were writing that doc, I'd write it as "If an equals sign and a string is appended to a keyword, that string will be used as the header for the data associated with the keyword".